# PsiClass to java Class

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing an intelliJ plugin where I need to get java class from PsiClass. For that I am writing this code,

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(psiClass.getQualifiedName());
```

But it is not working, giving `ClassNotFoundException`. For my use case, I want to access the methods of java class. I tried searching it and found this [relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155896/psiclass-to-java-lang-class)
where it is mentioned that it is not possible. Is there any workaround to achieve what I want.

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly